# Solving the constraint of a class that depends on a constraint

Tags: haskell, ghc, gadt

I am using `ConstraintKinds` and `MultiParamTypeClasses` to get a class that is parameterized by another class.

Assume `Foo m` says that types that satisfy the constraint `m` are pointed, that is, `(m a) => a`.  From that I try to use it to construct some `Bar m`.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}

class Foo m where
  foo :: (m a) => a

data Bar m where
  Bar :: ((m a) => a) -> Bar m

bar :: Foo m => Bar m
bar = Bar foo
```

But I get the following error.

```
Could not deduce (Foo m0) arising from a use of ‘foo’
      from the context: Foo m
```

From the context looks like `m0` should be `m`. Isn't there a way to make this work?

---

I think right now the problem is that I could define some `Foo Pointed a` first and then some `Foo Pointed2 a` and in that case `foo` would not know what to return, right? The idea is that I would call `(bar :: Bar Pointed)` or `(bar :: Bar Pointed2)` and get the two different results. Is something like this possible? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can do this with a type application to help GHC figure out which constraint you're talking about:

```
bar :: forall m . (Foo m) => Bar m
bar = Bar (foo @m)
```

Comment: But why is it needed? Since `m` appears as a parameter to `Bar` in the type, unification ought to be able to determine that this `m` is the one that's meant... oughtn't it?

Comment: @DanielWagner In the same way that GHC always expands e.g. the expression `length` (polymorphic) to `length @_unifVar` (monomorphic), it also always expands the hole in `Bar @m @a _` (constrained) to `Bar @m @a (/\{m a} -> _)` (pseudo-syntax, unconstrained). Putting just `foo` in that hole breaks, because its argument `m` is ambiguous (imagine adding another context `Foo m2` to `bar`—the open world assumption says it should still work, but it won't). Putting `foo @m` in that hole is fine.